# Drupal Custom Settings Wont Save

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Ok so I am wicked new to Drupal... like tonight new. I can't figure out what this code wont save.

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'page_node_form') {   
    $form['custom'] = array(
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => t('custom title'),
      '#weight' => -99,
      '#group' => 'additional_settings',
    );
  $form['custom']['custom_field'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Use this setting instead'),
      '#default_value' => '',
      '#description' => t('custom field'),
    );
  }
}
```

Am I missing a hook or something for saving? I assume someone who knows drupal knows where I am trying to add this but just in case I am trying to add this as a custom tab grouping when you go to edit a page. Like where it says Menu Settings, Revision Information, etc...

----------- EDIT ---------

So it looks like I have to add this line of code

`$form['#submit'][] = 'custom_node_form_submit';`

Comment: Hummm, but how can you bind that value to a `nid` then, which isn't there in the form when you are on the `node/add` page?